# Adding text view in horizontal pager

Tags: android, android-xml

```
 <FrameLayout 
android:id="@+id/frame_after_gallery"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

    <com.sb.Layouts.HorizontalPager 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@+id/ImageViewSwitcher"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
    </com.sb.Layouts.HorizontalPager>

    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/btn_previous" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grayleftarrow">
    </Button>   

    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/btn_next" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grayrightarrow">
    </Button>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is my xml, i am loading an image view in the horizontal pager, now i want to add a text view below that image view as a subtitle, which moves with the image.how to bring that text view below image view.
actually i have to keep both image and text in the same view so moving image also moves the text.

```
HorizontalPager imagePagingController;

 private void loadPagingImages() throws MalformedURLException
  {
   int totalCount = appdelegate.SportsEntries.allEntries.size();

   for (int j = 0; j < totalCount; j++)
   {
       ImageView view  = new ImageView(this); 
       view.setId(j);
       imagePagingController.addView(view);
       setImageDownloader(appdelegate.SportsEntries.allEntries.get(j), view);
   }

   currentpage =  imagePagingController.getCurrentScreen();
 }
```

i am loading that image like this in a view. now similarly want to add text view in that pager only below image view.